# Ckeditor in PHP

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

I have no issue in adding ckeditor to my webpage but when i insert a html source and submit the form. It returns the value with a html tag on it.

`<p>This is some <strong>sample text</strong>.</p>`

You can checkout the demo here http://www.ier.cl/intranet/OC/public/assets/javascript/ckeditor/_samples/php/standalone.php

How to remove the html tag on php?

Comment: use strip_tags() to remove html code. check here http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp

Comment: Have you tried [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)?

Comment: it's a bit weird when you used ckeditor just to strip the tags later.. well, as two comment above have suggested. you could use stript_tags -- but it will strip most of the tag.. also, [read the warning from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: Thank you guys i'll try those things.

Comment: It works but it shows plain text only i want to display as a html page

Comment: *facepalm* @KarthiKeyan, obviously it'll turn into **plain text** as you strip it of its html tags.. if you want to preserve it's formatting , leave it as is, only remove any `<script>` and `<iframe>` tags to prevent XSS attack.